# Bootstrap 3 buttons and input to be grouped in one row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of buttons and an input text box. But they are not aligned properly as shown.

```
    <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"> << </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"> < </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"> > </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"> >> </button>
            <input type="number" style="width: 30px; " class="form-control input-number" placeholder="84" maxlength="4" value="34" min="0" max="9999" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d4" />

        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Is there a way they are alligned in one row? Also notice that the size of the input box is looking different from the others. Is there a way to fix this too?

Comment: Have you checked the Navbar? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `btn-group` arranges all buttons in a row. like this

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">&lt;&lt;</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">&lt;</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">&gt;</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">&gt;&gt;</button>
  <input type="number" style="width: 30px; margin-top:10px" class="form-control input-number input-xs" placeholder="84" maxlength="4" value="34" min="0" max="9999" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d4" />
</div>
```

Note: When using HTML symbols(for example <,>) as text, then encode them as I did(Just a good practice).

[Docs btn-groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups)

And I used inline style for input type number `margin-top:10px;` because `input[type=number]` in bootstrap has `margin-bottom:10px;` so, to balance used margin-top. Instead you can use `margin-bottom:0px`

As @Mike Robinson said, even `.input-append` does the same . the difference is rounded borders and `input-append` is converted to `input-group` from [version 3](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/)

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-append">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">&lt;&lt;</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">&lt;</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">&gt;</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">&gt;&gt;</button>
  <input type="number" style="width: 30px; " class="form-control input-number input-xs" placeholder="84" maxlength="4" value="34" min="0" max="9999" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d4" />
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to use bootstrap 2.3.2 I'd recommend .input-append instead of .btn-group.

Comment: One note - input groups do not support multiple .input-group-btn elements . It's only one .input-group-btn for each side, with the buttons all going inside the element. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic

Answer (score 5):

You need an input-group. You can add on groups of buttons to either side of the input. Here they'll be on the left:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> << </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> < </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> > </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> >> </button>
    </div>

    <input type="number" style="width: 30px; " class="form-control input-number" placeholder="84" maxlength="4" value="34" min="0" max="9999" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d4" />
</div>
```

Read more about it here:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-multiple

Comment: Thank You Mike, its a simple one I missed it out some how.

Answer (score 1):

The form-control style on your input is the thing that's moving it to the next line. It's doing so because the form-control style in bootstrap is set to display: block. By adding a new style or doing an inline style you can get them on the same page.

For instance:

```
<input type="number" style="width: 30px; " class="form-control input-number" placeholder="84" maxlength="4" value="34" min="0" max="9999" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d4" style="display: initial;" />
```

Or you can make a class such as:

```
.newInputControl{
display: inline;
}
<input type="number" style="width: 30px; " class="form-control input-number" placeholder="84" maxlength="4" value="34" min="0" max="9999" autocomplete="off" pattern="\d4" class="newInputControl" />
```

You can also take care of it using bootstrap, which has built the framework to handle this by placing your form-control inside an input group.

Answer (score -1):

use:
**form-control-static** instead of **form-control** in your input text

Comment: .form-control-static is for paragraph tags, mostly to ensure they have the same sizing as .form-control elements